# Force or require a payment type with Paypal api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

Do I have to call paypal to setup a billing agreement if I only want to accept insant payments?  I have a rails app that I am testing in sandbox with paypal express checkout.  Looking at the paypal api, I have seen there's a way to do what I want with the billing_agreement parameter, which I have seen used in setup_purchase().  I have also read that acquiring a billing agreement for recurring payments requires calling paypal.  I am not interested in recurring payments.  My setup_purchase method is below and works except that it still allows echecks.  Thanks for considering.

```
setup_response = gateway.setup_purchase(amount, :billing_agreement => {:payment_type => 'InstantOnly'}, :ip => request.remote_ip, :return_url => return_url, :cancel_return_url => polymorphic_url([@parent,@offer]), :items => [{:name => item_name, :quantity => 1, :description => item_description, :amount => amount}])
```

Comment: At the bottom of the page could be a solution, I'm trying to see if active merchant supports it. https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECImmediatePayment

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, what you're after is called [reference transactions](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECReferenceTxns).  You need to call PayPal to have them enable this for you.  If you were just using recurring payments alone you wouldn't need to call, and whether you're using it or not you'll have access to it.

What you want to do, though, is run through Express Checkout and complete and authorization or a sale transaction.  Make sure you include the billing agreement parameters in your SetExpressCheckout request when you do this.

Then, you can use [DoReferenceTransaction](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/doreferencetransaction-api-operation-nvp) to process payments in the future without sending the user through the whole process again.  You simply pass in the previous transaction ID you got back from the Express Checkout flow along with a new amount you'd like to charge. PayPal uses the data saved to process it without further approval.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for replying. I hope I'm understanding right. I have no interest setting up future or recurring payments. I just want to restrict the payment type to exclude echecks. Unfortunately, the link I provided states Immediate Payment also excludes Electronic Funds Transfer (which I want.) Not to mention activemerchant would have to be changed to support that api operation. I'm afraid there isn't a solution to my problem and I will have to handle echecks and setup an IPN listener. Ideas still very welcome.

Comment: I didn't realize that's all your primary goal is.  You can easily solve that problem by disabling e-checks in your PayPal profile under Payment Receiving Preferences.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the reason that's not an option is that it's others' paypal seller accounts that will be used on my site. So it's not like I can change a setting one time and be done with it :/

Comment: Ok, well with the Express Checkout API you can include the ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD parameter in your SetExpressCheckout request and set it to InstantPaymentOnly.

Comment: Yeah, although that would exclude electronic fund transfers, so I don't think that'll be an option.  I was reading activemerchant's source and didn't find the ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD so I'd have to add it.  Also, I saw that parameter in the uk sopa api but not the USA's.

Comment: Ok, I'm not following you then.  an electronic transfer is the same thing as an e-check, so I'm confused about what you're trying to do.  Sounds like you're making things tougher on yourself than they need to be.

Comment: You're right, that is what I want. As per https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/paypal/paypal_common_api.rb adding allowed_payment_method_type to the options should create that xml tag. Unfortunately it doesn't have an affect. I have tried adding FundingSourceDetails and reordering the xml to match paypal's documentation(which does have an affect but not a desired one.) Activemerchant supports version 72 paypal's api and the documentation I've been reading is the current version(94).